# Problema con URL con acentos bs4 requests python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Como puedo hacer para que tome el link completo ? porque solo me toma hasta la c y necesito del acento porque sino no puedo acceder a la url. perdon si algo esta mal pero es la primera vez que pregunto aqui.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
baseurl ="https://www.greendeco.com.ar"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get("https://www.greendeco.com.ar/cesped-sintetico")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('div',class_="_2zTHN _2AHc6")

productlinks=[]

for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])
print(productlinks)

['https://www.greendeco.com.ar/product-page/césped-20mm', 'https://www.greendeco.com.ar/product-page/césped-30mm', 'https://www.greendeco.com.ar/product-page/césped-40mm']
```

Comment: Veo que al final está la lista de URLs que obtienes a partir de tu script. Supongo que quieres acceder a estas URLs y te arroja un error.

Comment: si me sale la lista pero no me queda como un link sino que se me corta el link en la C. En my Pycharm hasta la c esta en azul y si clickeo para acceder al link el link me queda recortado a esto https://www.greendeco.com.ar/product-page/c

Comment: Osea que la lista que pusiste al final no es el resultado del script, ¿Más bien es lo que deseas obtener?

Comment: me sale esa lista pero me queda asi greendeco.com.ar/product-page/c hasta aqui en azul como si fuera un link y el resto en texto asi con las 3 url.

Comment: Si tu IDE no muestra la URL completa, debe ser un problema con su configuración de encoding.

Si el script es incapaz de obtener la URL completa, entonces deberás hacer una conversión del encoding de la página web al encoding de tu script.

Comment: Para usar una URL así, siempre hay que escaparla primero: `https://www.greendeco.com.ar/product-page/c%C3%A9sped-20mm`